# Android Device - Remote Mirroring

Tags: android, adb, remote-debugging, mobile-development, screen-recording

Dear Developers/Experts/Architect

I have the following requirements. I am looking for your expert guidance to find out the best way to fulfill the business requirement.

```
   1. List the available Android version with model names in the dropdown.
   2. upon choosing a valid device from the list, mirror the device at the local laptop.
   3. End-user will perform some action (like configuring WIFI/install app from play store) into a mirrored device.
   4. Once step 3 is complete, end-user click on submit
   5. End-user action will be recorded and send for verification
   6. mirroring section will be running on Windows OS
```

There are external tools available in the market (like Vysar,scrcpy) which can be used. The licensed Vysar version has advanced mirroring and remote mirroring sections features enabled as well. But Business wants us to make our own mirroring system.

I am just a beginner in the mobile development area, I would like expert guidance here. Please advise.

Comment: "I am just a beginner in the mobile development area" -- this is *not* something that I would recommend a beginner attempt to work on. `scrcpy` is open source, so you might be able to use it as a starting point. You might see if Genymotion offers consulting services that might help your firm create what you are seeking. However, in terms of Stack Overflow, your question is far too broad.

Comment: Thanks, CommonWare for the response!  I shall start to understand and take some training on Genymotion

Comment: FYI, the reason I mentioned Genymotion is that `scrpy` is one of their open source projects.